# How to write python code to use blockdiag package

Tags: python, blockdiag

I would like to display some data in a list by block diagram.
I am trying to implement this [Example](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/pyensae/helpsphinx/notebooks/draw_diagram.html) but not able to write correct python code.

It will be great if someone can guide me. How can I execute blockdiag codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this discussion and it runs for me. Add your strings in the source.

You can use blockdiag API like this::

```
from blockdiag import parser, builder, drawer
tree = parser.parse_string(source)
diagram = builder.ScreenNodeBuilder.build(tree)
draw = drawer.DiagramDraw('PNG', diagram, filename="foo.png")
draw.draw()
draw.save()
```

This is another example using blockdiag API
(works at http://interactive.blockdiag.com/ )
https://bitbucket.org/tk0miya/blockdiag_interactive_shell